# No muestra el resultado de la consulta

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que me muestre todos los resultados de una tabla con un par de parametros y luego codificarlos en json, sin embargo en la consulta que hago no se muestran los resultados de la tabla, y solo me trae de vuelta un solo resultado, cual puede ser mi error, ya que no lo veo.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `transacciones` WHERE `Usercorreo` = '$Username'");

while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
  $response["ComCorreo"] = $array['ComCorreo'];
  $ComCorreo = $array['ComCorreo'];
  $response["monto"] = $array['monto'];
  $response["fecha"] = $array['fecha'];
  $response["concepto"] = $array['concepto'];
  $comrsql=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT *  FROM `comercios` WHERE `Comcorreo`='$ComCorreo'");
  while($rowid=mysqli_fetch_array($comrsql)) {
    $response["COMERCIONOMBRE"] =$rowid['nombre'];
    $response["COMERCIOLOGO"] =$rowid['logo'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta fue la forma como lo hice y funciono:

```
while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $temp = array();
            $temp["idTrans"] = $array['idTrans'];
            $temp["ComCorreo"] = $array['ComCorreo'];
            $ComCorreo = $array['ComCorreo'];
            $monto = $array['monto'];
            $monto_bonito = number_format($monto, 2, '.', ',');
            $temp["monto"] = $monto_bonito;
            $temp["fecha"] = $array['fecha'];
            $temp["concepto"] = $array['concepto'];

        //array_push($response["movimientos"], $temp);
        $comrsql=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT *  FROM `comercios` WHERE `Comcorreo`='$ComCorreo'");
                    while($rowid=mysqli_fetch_array($comrsql)){
                        //$comtemp = array();
                        $temp["COMERCIONOMBRE"] =$rowid['nombre'];
                        $temp["COMERCIORIF"] =$rowid['rif'];
                        $response["COMERCIOLOGO"] =$rowid['logo'];
                    array_push($response["movimientos"], $temp);      
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás sobreescribiendo todo el rato la misma variable, hazte una nueva y listo: (Lo otro que dices no lo entiendo)

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `transacciones` WHERE `Usercorreo` = '$Username'");
$misdatos = array()
while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
  $response["ComCorreo"] = $array['ComCorreo'];
  $ComCorreo = $array['ComCorreo'];
  $response["monto"] = $array['monto'];
  $response["fecha"] = $array['fecha'];
  $response["concepto"] = $array['concepto'];
  $comrsql=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT *  FROM `comercios` WHERE `Comcorreo`='$ComCorreo'");
  while($rowid=mysqli_fetch_array($comrsql)) {
    $misdatos[] = array(
            'COMERCIONOMBRE' => $rowid['nombre'],
            'COMERCIOLOGO' => $rowid['logo'],
    )
  }
}
$mijson = json_encode($misdatos);
```

Comment: Aun cuando coloco la informacion como tu dices necesito un resultado del tipo: {"ComCorreo":"info@gmail.com","monto":"45000.00","fecha":"2017-08-22","concepto":"Pago ","COMERCIONOMBRE":"Fitness Universal","COMERCIOLOGO":"logo\/1.png","success":true} sin embaro, puedo hacer una consulta simple e igualmente solo me muestra un registro, yo quiero que me los muestre todos

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Daniel estubo bien pero incompleta, el codigo despues de verlo quedo de la siguiente forma:

`while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $response["ComCorreo"] = $array['ComCorreo'];
            $ComCorreo = $array['ComCorreo'];
            $response["monto"] = $array['monto'];
            $response["fecha"] = $array['fecha'];
            $response["concepto"] = $array['concepto'];
            echo json_encode($response);
            $comrsql=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT *  FROM comercios WHERE Comcorreo='$ComCorreo'");
                        while($rowid=mysqli_fetch_array($comrsql)){
                            $datos["COMERCIONOMBRE"] =$rowid['nombre'];
                            $datos["COMERCIOLOGO"] =$rowid['logo'];
                            echo json_encode($datos);
                        }
        }`

Donde en cada while es que muestro el resultado json del array, con esta estructura hago una consulta anidada a dos tablas, y se muestra un json que se puede recuperar desde otras aplicaciones

Answer (score 0):

```
**iNTENTA HACERLO DE EN ESTA MANERA. Espero te ayude Bendiciones.**

<?php


        require('conexion.php');

        $consultas="SELECT *  FROM alumnos";

        $resultados=$conectahugo->query($consultas);

        while($columnas=$resultados->fetch_assoc()){

        echo $columnas['id'],' ';
        echo $columnas['nombrep'],' ';
        echo $columnas['descripcion'],' ';
        echo $columnas['precio'],' ';


        echo '<br>';
        }
```

?>